# "That house is made..." – of vs. from vs. with vs. by (a material)

Tags: prepositions, definite-article, proper-nouns

For example:

> That house is made **of** the Stone.
>   That house is made **from** the Stone.
>   That house is made **with** the Stone.
>   That house is made **by** the Stone.

Which of these prepositions is correct in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The differences would depend on how each of the sentences was finished although you have a choice of preposition for most constructions and the word *stone* should not be capitalised. For example:

> That house is made of the stone that comes from the quarry.
>
> That house is made from the stone that my grandfather quarried.
>
> That house is made with the stone that was taken from the old ruin.
>
> That house is made by the Stone family builders.

In the first three examples, you could use *of*, *with* or *from*.

*Stone" in the fourth example needs to refer to a name if it is capitalised.

Using *by* indicates an agent - the maker - or a method, *by using hollow bricks". The other three prepositions all serve to tell you something about the stone itself.